# Getting Data from wtforms

Tags: python, input, flask, wtforms, word2vec

i've been experimenting with word2vec and gensim as its python implementation. Now i have to make my model accesible on a Website - so i need Flask. I defined a Form in forms.py like that:

```
from wtforms Import Form, StringField, SubmitField, validators
class msForm(Form):
    ms_1 = StringField(label='Eingabe_1', default = 'king', validators=[validators.input_required()])
    ms_2 = StringField(label='Eingabe_2', default = 'man', validators=[validators.input_required()])
    ms_3 = StringField(label='Eingabe_3', default = 'queen', validators=[validators.input_required()])
    submit=SubmitField()
```

now my views.py looks like:

```
from app import app
from .forms import msForm
from flask import render_template, flash, request
from gensim.models import word2vec

global model
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('./app/static/GoT.model.vector', binary=True)
global form
form = msForm()

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('my-form.html', form=form)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def msForm_post():
    text1 = form.ms_1.data
    text2 = form.ms_2.data
    text3 = form.ms_3.data      
    processed_text = model.most_similar(positive=[text3, text2], negative = [text1])        
    return processed_text[0][0]
```

When i execute my run.py, go to http://localhost:5000/, change my Input and click the 'Submit' button, i only get the answer on my default-input. Why doesnt he send my Input?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english,
FFoDWindow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate the form in the view, not as a single global.  You're using the same form instance over and over, and that instance was created without any form data.  You can group both GET and POST in one view.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = msForm(request.form)
    # request.form not needed when using Flask-WTF

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        processed_text = model.most_similar(positive=[form.ms_3.data, form.ms_2.data], negative=[form.ms_1.data])
        return processed_text[0][0]

    return render_template('my-form.html', form=form)
```